# How to break iframe and redirect page with Jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, break

How can i understand that my page is being called from iframe and break it with jquery ? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if (self !== top)
    top.location.replace(self.location.href)
```

that's how you break out of a frame

Comment: would this break facebook canvas page frame ?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea but as long as it's in a physical frame or iframe it should (never touched FB in my life).

Comment: well i will give it a shot at least. i put this javascript code before head tag close and it should work right ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG well... you might have to put it in a script tag first like so: `<script type="text/javascript">if(self!==top)top.location.replace(self.location.href)</script>`  that should do it.  Just put that in the head tag.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in plain Javascript since `top` and `location` are both objects attached to the global `window` object provided in all major browsers.

```
if (top.location != location){
    location.href = 'http://google.com';
}
```

Comment: I see what you are trying... but really... you don't need to wait for the DOM to load before checking the location and redirecting... so this isn't really a jQuery *version*

Comment: Very true. I just have a chronic case of wrapping everything in `$(document).ready(function(){});` because if I do it all the time, I'll never forget :P

Comment: Sorry, but not a useful answer. The wrapping of the code in the  the jquery document ready stuff actually just worsens the functionality by making it wait until after the DOM loads to switch pages, giving a flash of the page within the iframe before redirect. Pointless additions based on habit I understand, but the fact that your addition actually worsens the functionality means a -1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

if you really want a JQuery solution here it is (Crossbrowser, and works fine even if $ is something else in the scoop):

```
(function($) { 

    if($(document) !== top)
    top.location.replace($(document).location.href)

})(jQuery);
```

Even though its *unnecessary and overkill* because it can be done easier with vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Wouldn't accounting for scope be better accomplished by just using "jQuery" in those 2 spots instead of "$"?